# getting error in bytebuffer column in java class

Tags: java, jpa, serialization

I have made an entity in Jpa as shown below and it is working fine at the end it is representing the table as per the Jpa specifications now in this entity I have kept a member of type ByteBuffer so that at the backend in the corresponding table it is of Blob Data type , now the problem is that functionality is working fine but when i scan the code as per sonar lint for this class it gives me the exception that makes "configuration" transient  or serializable .

But the point is that my class already implements serializable so please advise how to overcome this problem, please advise

```
@Table( value = "abc_configurations" )
public class Abc implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 22528067957L;


    @PrimaryKeyColumn( name = "abcCode", type = PARTITIONED )
    private String abcCode;


    @Column
    private ByteBuffer configuration;

    // setters and getteres
    //default constructor 

    }
```

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What it is *actually* telling you is that `ByteBuffer` isn't `Serializable`. So you can't use it. Use a byte array, or maybe a `String`.

Comment: The problem is that you declared it `Serializable` for JPA persistence, but sonar lint uses rules designed for Java’s builtin Serialization.